# Is there anyway to ignore the *failure: Avoided redundant navigation to current location* error using Vue Router and just refresh the page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I see this question has been asked a few times on here, but none of the answers have really helped me in this current situation.

I have an app I'm working on with a sidebar with tabs that link to different dashboards. Each of the *SidebarLinks* are a `router-link` with the `to` key being fed the `route` prop from the main component.

Inside one of these dashboards, the **Analysis** dashboard, there is another router that routes you to child routes for specific *Analyses* with their own ids (EX: */analysis/1*).

The user clicks on a button for a specific analysis and they are routed to a page containing that information, on the same page.

**The Error**
When I click the **Analysis** **SidebarLink** the route in the url changes back to */analysis*, but the page doesn't update/refresh.

I don't get an error in the console, but I do get the *failure* in the devtools.

I understand that Vue Router doesn't route back to a route you are already on, but I need it to. If you refresh the page when the url is just */analysis* it routes back to it's inital state.

Is there anyway to refresh when it rereoutes to */analysis*? Or a way to handle this error to work as intended?

**What I've tried**

- I've tried changing the `router-link` to an `<a>` tag and programatically use `router.push` and then `catch` the error, but that doesn't do anything.
- I've tried checking if the `route.fullPath.contains("/analysis")` and then just do `router.back()` but that doesn't seem to work either.
  **SidebarLink router function**

```
function goToRoute() {
      console.log(`route.fullPath → `, route.fullPath)
      if (route.fullPath.match('/analysis*') as any) {
        console.log('route includes /analysis')
        router.back()
      } else {
        console.log('route doesnt inclue /analysis')
        router
          .push({
            path: props.route,
          })
          .catch(() => {})
      }
    }
```

**Inital /analysis Page**
This is what the page looks like normally
[image]

**/analysis/1 Page**
This is what the route to *analysis/1* looks like (url changes)
[image]

**/analysis/1 Page When Issue Analysis SidebarLink Clicked**
This is what the route to *analysis* looks like when the sidebarlink is clicked (url changes, but the page stays the same)
[image]

Comment: I had someting similar, I did it by watching the $route param, if you haven't tried that, tell me and I will make an answer explainig how to do

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! 
I haven't tried that before and would definitely love a break down if you have the time; I'm starting to lose my mind with this error.

Comment: @Medab So I put a log at the first line of the `goToRoute()` and when I am on *'/analysis/1'* and then click the sidebarLink, the route.params logs out `route.params →  {id: '1'}` the first time. And then if you click it again, since the url/route changes to *'/analysis'*, it will log out *'/analysis'*. I havent tried it with a watcher, but I think even the first time you click the sidebarLink and it returns *'/analysis/1'* is a bit concerning. 
What would you do inside of the watcher then to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are fetching your data from a backend service or data files
If yes you can refetch the data everytime the route param changed by watching it.

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.id': function (id) {
    if(id)
     this.$store.dispatch('fetchOneAnalys', id)
else 
 this.$store.dispatch('fetchAllAnalyses')
    }
```